# EF5 default table name convention causes 'Invalid object name' exception

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, naming-conventions, entity-framework-5

I have a model with several entities in my MVC4 project with VS 2012. Recently I added a view to my DB named 'vwTeacherNames' and I tried to update the model and I unchecked the `Plorizing` option for that update.

Then, I rename my entity to 'TeacherName'. Now when I tun the Prj, this exception is thrown where I define a DropDownList for teachers:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.TeacherNames'.
```

I tried many ways such as using custom tool, removing the .tt files and generating the again, ... However the problem stays firm!

So, how can I tell the EF the right table(in fact view) name which is `vwTeacherNames`?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! and I add it here with some more tweaks:

```
public class myDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PtDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    ... //some entities

    //Here it is:

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TeacherName>().Property(t => t.FullName)
            .HasColumnName("TeacherName");

        modelBuilder.Entity<TeacherName>().ToTable("vwTeacherNames", schemaName: "dbo");                        

    }
}
```

**Update:** Why waisting your time by defining what you previously defined?! Just kill the default table naming convention and enjoy progressing your Prj:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Adding this line tells the EF not to go through that convention
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();               
    }
```

So, It should builds up your queries by `EntitySetName` and `EntityName` properties of your entities which the first of is the DB table name and the second is your entity name which you use in your DbContext.